# Signal path / configuration help for a PLL for AWG

Tags: pcb, signal, pll, configuration, schematic

In our system signal path, there is a clock signal being sent from the FPGA noted as SCLK. This goes to each component not including the MCU.

The  way I understand this is that the PLL receives the SCLK signal and the output signal from the DAC

Top Level
[image: Top Level]

COMPin is mapped as SCLK and DACOut is the DAC output signal we're trying to lock with the SCLK.

Do we have this misconfigured? I keep going in circles while reading the datasheet and realize I don't understand the function of the PLL. Any recommendations or guidance would be greatly appreciated. I can include more context if needed but for this stage in the process we're just outputting our signal from the DAC to the PLL and finally to the filter.

PLL Schematic
[image: PLL Schematic]

PLL Part

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc7046a.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1616775891129
[image: PLL Part]